# Get BoundingBox of a transparent Image?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

i load a transparent .png into an UIImage.

How to i calculte the real bounding-box. E.g. if the the real image is smaller than the .png-dimensions.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Let me rephrase: "How do I find the smallest rectangle in an partially transparent image that contains all pixels with an alpha value above a certain threshold?". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Got an answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521987/crop-uiimage-to-alpha and user404709's answer works for me.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming "bounding box of an image" is simply a rectangle in the image, specified in pixel coordinates.

You want the rectangle of `image` which contains all pixels with an alpha greater than `threshold` (it is equivalent to say that all pixels that are not in this rectangle have an alpha lower than `threshold`). After that you can transform this rectangle in screen coordinate (or whatever you want).

The basic algorithm is to start with a rectangle containing the whole image, then shrink the rectangle horizontally, then vertically (or vertically then horizontally).

I don't know Objective-C, so I put the code in pure C (some functions are just to make the code more clearer):

```
typedef struct Rectangle
{
    unsigned int x1, y1, x2, y2;
} Rectangle;

typedef struct Image
{
    unsigned int height,width;
    unsigned int* data;
} Image;

unsigned char getPixelAlpha(Image* img, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned int pixel = 0; // default = fully transparent

    if(x >= img->width || y >= img->height)
        return pixel; // Consider everything not in the image fully transparent

    pixel = img->data[x + y * img->width];
    return (unsigned char)((pixel & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

void shrinkHorizontally(Image* img, unsigned char threshold, Rectangle* rect)
{
    int x, y;

    // Shrink from left
    for(x = 0; x < (int)img->width; x++)
    {
        // Find the maximum alpha of the vertical line at x
        unsigned char lineAlphaMax = 0;
        for(y = 0; y < (int)img->height; y++)
        {
            unsigned char alpha = getPixelAlpha(img,x,y);
            if(alpha > lineAlphaMax)
                lineAlphaMax = alpha;
        }

        // If at least on pixel of the line if more opaque than 'threshold'
        // then we found the left limit of the rectangle
        if(lineAlphaMax >= threshold)
        {
            rect->x1 = x;
            break;
        }
    }


    // Shrink from right
    for(x = img->width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        // Find the maximum alpha of the vertical line at x
        unsigned char lineAlphaMax = 0;
        for(y = 0; y < (int)img->height; y++)
        {
            unsigned char alpha = getPixelAlpha(img,x,y);
            if(alpha > lineAlphaMax)
                lineAlphaMax = alpha;
        }

        // If at least on pixel of the line if more opaque than 'threshold'
        // then we found the right limit of the rectangle
        if(lineAlphaMax >= threshold)
        {
            rect->x2 = x;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Almost the same than shrinkHorizontally.
void shrinkVertically(Image* img, unsigned char threshold, Rectangle* rect)
{
    int x, y;

    // Shrink from up
    for(y = 0; y < (int)img->height; y++)
    {
        // Find the maximum alpha of the horizontal line at y
        unsigned char lineAlphaMax = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < (int)img->width; x++)
        {
            unsigned char alpha = getPixelAlpha(img,x,y);
            if(alpha > lineAlphaMax)
                lineAlphaMax = alpha;
        }

        // If at least on pixel of the line if more opaque than 'threshold'
        // then we found the up limit of the rectangle
        if(lineAlphaMax >= threshold)
        {
            rect->y1 = x;
            break;
        }
    }


    // Shrink from bottom
    for(y = img->height- 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        // Find the maximum alpha of the horizontal line at y
        unsigned char lineAlphaMax = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < (int)img->width; x++)
        {
            unsigned char alpha = getPixelAlpha(img,x,y);
            if(alpha > lineAlphaMax)
                lineAlphaMax = alpha;
        }

        // If at least on pixel of the line if more opaque than 'threshold'
        // then we found the bottom limit of the rectangle
        if(lineAlphaMax >= threshold)
        {
            rect->y2 = x;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Find the 'real' bounding box
Rectangle findRealBoundingBox(Image* img, unsigned char threshold)
{
    Rectangle r = { 0, 0, img->width, img->height };
    shrinkHorizontally(img,threshold,&r);
    shrinkVertically(img,threshold,&r);
    return r;
}
```

Now that you have the coordinates of the bounding box in pixel in your image, you should be able to transform it in device coordinates.

Comment: There's a possible (though uncommon) problem. `x` is `unsigned` in `shrinkHorizontally`, yet you're looping with `for(x = img->width - 1; x >= 0; x--)` to shrink from the right. Similar for `y` in `shrinkVertically`. There won't be undefined behavior since `getPixelAlpha` checks the bounds, but if threshold is too high (compared to the image), it will loop indefinitely. Also, you could speed up the search a little by not reconsidering already processed pixels (though the big-O performance won't change).

Comment: You mean, is the size of the image is (0,0) or (w,0) or (0,h) ?

Comment: Well, that's another problem if `Image`s are allowed to have a dimension be `0`. What I meant, however, is if there wasn't a pixel whose alpha channel was greater than or equal to `threshold`. Say `threshold = 0xFF` but all pixels have `getPixelAlpha(img,x,y) <= 0xFE` (as I said, uncommon). Then `lineAlphaMax >= threshold` will never be true, so you'll never `break` out of the outer loop. Instead, the loop will run as expected until the loop iterator `x--` runs when `x` is `0` (for `shrinkHorizontally`). This will cause `x` to wrap to `UINT_MAX`, which is `>= 0`. The loop will run forever.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I just noticed you failed to shift `(pixel & 0xFF000000);` before casting it in `getPixelAlpha`. That will always return `0`. Also, I might be getting a little language lawyer-y here (don't worry, it's not about the type widths), but make sure `img->height` and `img->width` are `> 0` and `<= INT_MAX`.

Comment: Fixed. The solution is not meant to be exhaustive ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect myImageViewRect = [myImageView frame];
CGSize myImageSize = [[myImageView image]size];

if(myImageSize.width < myImageViewRect.size.width){
   NSLog(@"it's width smaller!");
}
if(myImageSize.height < myImageViewRect.size.height){
   NSLog(@"it's height smaller!");
}
```

If you want the image to resize to the size of the image view you can call

```
[myImageView sizeToFit];
```