# Getting UIImage for only particular area bounds drawn - PaintView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, paint

I have already implemented paint / draw using:

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
-(void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
```

Now issue is that for any line drawn, I want to get that particular line / paint image. I don't want image of entire screen, only area / bounds of line / paint drawn.

Reason is that I want to perform pan gesture / delete functionality on that line / paint drawn.

User can draw multiple lines, so want `UIImage` for all this lines separately.

Any logic or code snippet will be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, particularly how many times you plan on doing this in a row, you may be able to create a different image/layer for each paint line.  Your final image would essentially be all the individual lines drawn on top of each other.

It may be more efficient to create a custom view to capture touch events.  You could store the list of touch coordinates for each paint line and render them all at once in a custom drawRect.  This way you are storing lists of coordinates for each paint line, and can still access each one, instead of a list of images.  You could calculate the area/bounds from the coordinates used to render the line.

Additional context and code may be helpful, I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your paint/draw methods so myself or others may be able to accomplish that more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I take a look at the MVPaint project. It seems you have an object:

`MVPaintDrawing` _drawing;

which contains an array of `MVPaintTransaction`. You can iterate on those `MVPaintTransaction` to draw an `UIImage`.

So first you can add a method to get an image from a `MVPaintTransaction`:

```
- (UIImage *) imageToDrawWithSize:(CGSize) size xScale:(CGFloat)xScale yScale:(CGFloat)yScale {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xScale, yScale);

    // call the existing draw method    
    [self draw];

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Then add a method to get an array of image from the array of `MVPaintTransaction` in the `MVPaintDrawing` class:

```
- (NSArray *) getImagesFromDrawingOnSurface: (UIImageView *) surface xScale: (CGFloat) xScale yScale: (CGFloat) yScale{

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (MVPaintTransaction * transaction in _drawing) {
        UIImage *image = [transaction imageToDrawWithSize:surface.frame.size xScale:xScale yScale:yScale];
        [imageArray addObject:image];
    }

    return imageArray;
}
```

In this way you will have an array of `UIImage` corresponding to each line you have drawn. If you want those images to have the "minimum" possible size (i mean without extra alpha part), you can apply [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521987/crop-uiimage-to-alpha) (I added it in the `MVPaintTransaction` class):

```
- (UIImage *)trimmedImage:(UIImage *)img {

    CGImageRef inImage = img.CGImage;
    CFDataRef m_DataRef;
    m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));

    UInt8 * m_PixelBuf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef);

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    CGPoint top,left,right,bottom;

    BOOL breakOut = NO;
    for (int x = 0;breakOut==NO && x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int loc = x + (y * width);
            loc *= 4;
            if (m_PixelBuf[loc + 3] != 0) {
                left = CGPointMake(x, y);
                breakOut = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    breakOut = NO;
    for (int y = 0;breakOut==NO && y < height; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

            int loc = x + (y * width);
            loc *= 4;
            if (m_PixelBuf[loc + 3] != 0) {
                top = CGPointMake(x, y);
                breakOut = YES;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    breakOut = NO;
    for (int y = height-1;breakOut==NO && y >= 0; y--) {

        for (int x = width-1; x >= 0; x--) {

            int loc = x + (y * width);
            loc *= 4;
            if (m_PixelBuf[loc + 3] != 0) {
                bottom = CGPointMake(x, y);
                breakOut = YES;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    breakOut = NO;
    for (int x = width-1;breakOut==NO && x >= 0; x--) {

        for (int y = height-1; y >= 0; y--) {

            int loc = x + (y * width);
            loc *= 4;
            if (m_PixelBuf[loc + 3] != 0) {
                right = CGPointMake(x, y);
                breakOut = YES;
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    CGFloat scale = img.scale;

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(left.x / scale, top.y/scale, (right.x - left.x)/scale, (bottom.y - top.y) / scale);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( cropRect.size,
                                           NO,
                                           scale);
    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y)
            blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy
                alpha:1.];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CFRelease(m_DataRef);
    return croppedImage;
}
```

Then simply replace in the first method:

```
return result;
```

by

```
return [self trimmedImage:result];
```

Comment: Well I tried it too before posting and if I call getImagesFromDrawingOnSurface, I get an array of UIImage (each image represent a drawn line which is what you ask for). My code doesnt change the way lines are displayed (to do this you may need to create array of UIImageView for example).